# What's more efficient, read a file everytime or search data in an array

Tags: c++, performance

I have to implement a program in C++ using 2 files, "stock.txt" that has information about products of a store, and "sales.txt", this has the products that has been sold. I have to compare the sales for each product and get the amount of product that has been sold using a sequential solution, and a parallel solution making use of threads to compare the ms of difference between both solutions,  it's for a University homework.

The homework statement specifies that "sales.txt" has to be read every time that I executed a solution.

Here's my question. What's more efficient, read the stock.txt file every time as I do with "sales.txt" and make the comparison, or storage the "stock.txt" information in an array, list, etc and each time that I want to compare information of both files, search for the features of an specific product in the array, list, whatever?

Comment: _"The homework statement specifies that "sales.txt" has to be read everytime that I executed a solution."_ How would you plan to keep the once read file _in an array_ between separate program executions?

Comment: "What's more efficient, read a file everytime or search data in an array" - Obviously reading data in RAM is faster than reading it from disk.

Comment: Usually, reading the data once and storing it in array is faster.  But any modern OS will buffer the file if there's enough free RAM to make it feasible, so rereading might not be that much slower; if RAM is low, however, it'll depend on the kind of disk you have---spinning disk is slower than SSD, which is slower than Intel's latest tech.  But if you load a large file and doing so exhausts RAM, it can cause [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) which may incur a bigger penalty.  So if they haven't covered this already, this may be a good question to raise in your class.

Comment: Most efficient is relative.  For files small enough to be read in whole into RAM with no swapping, loading into RAM.  When the files grow to be larger than are able to be stored in RAM, reading, but strategically.  In fact, most modern operating systems are pretty aggressive about caching read files, so you would likely see very little performance increase if you were to cache small files yourself.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  both solutions are in the same program, I could use any of them in the same program execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's more efficient, read the stock.txt file everytime as I do with "sales.txt" and make the comparison, or storage the "stock.txt" information in an array, list, etc and each time that I want to compare information of both files, search for the features of an specific product in the array, list, whatever?

To really know, you should implement *both* solutions and benchmark them.

In practice, for a small `sales.txt` file, it does not matter much. In principle, doing file IO is usually slightly (and sometimes a lot) slower than working in memory (e.g. by a factor x10 to x10000). But a small file resides entirely in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), so the difference won't matter a lot (and computers are [really fast](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answer) today).

If you organize your data in memory by using efficient [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) (perhaps with the help of standard C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) you could have a logarithmic (or better) [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) which is much better than a linear search in a file. In some cases, [hash-tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) would be useful and they give a constant-time access.

In real life, [point-of-sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) software is likely to use some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (you could consider [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or a real [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) like [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)) and require [transaction processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing), i.e. [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) properties in [database transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). Then, be sure to have good [database indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) so spend time in defining your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema).

Answer (score 1):

Even if the file you read several times stay in the cache to read the file is slower, furthermore you are not limited to array or whatever and can use more adapted representation (map ...) to quickly find a data from key(s)

*But* efficiency is not limited to the cpu time, if you have a large amount of data to read this can be a problem, be sure in a bank all the accounts are not in memory, the databases do not exist not nothing (and not only to allow parallel accesses).